# Explain why in a ring the additive neutral can not have a multiplicative inverse.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Explain why in a ring the additive neutral can not have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Write down the cancellation law and how it applies to $a\cdot b=0$?

Comment: yes, prove it with the cancellation law

Comment: Explain why in a ring the additive neutral can not have a multiplicative inverse.